# how to remove space character between number character?

Tags: php, string, space

I have string like this:

```
$str = "old iccid : 809831 3245 345 new iccid : 999000 112221"
```

How to remove the space character between number character in PHP, to become this output?

```
$output = "old iccid : 8098313245345 new iccid : 999000112221";
```

Comment: `preg_replace()` would do it if your words don't mix letters and digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer from xdazz (http://stackoverflow.com/users/762073/xdazz), this syntax works well.

```
$output = preg_replace('/(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)/', '', $str);
```

Comment: Copying other people's answers and redundantly posting them on Stackoverflow -- is not valuable for Stackoverflow or its researchers.

Answer (score 1):

Separate the digits from characters and use

```
$str="809831 3245 345";
$foo= str_replace(' ','',$str);
echo $foo; // gives 8098313245345
```

Comment: And what would be the output for `$str = "old iccid : 809831 3245 345 new iccid : 999000 112221"` ???

Comment: @Havelock that's why i mentioned '_seperate digits from characters_'

Comment: This is 100% incorrect.  Proof: https://3v4l.org/ANLtJ  It removes all spaces in the string and that is not the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: this is NOT the answer. See comments.

`$output = preg_replace( '/\d[ *]\d/', '', $str);`

Comment: I've checked again, those code didn't work well..
it's delete character near space, which was resulted like this: 
$output = "old iccid : 80983245345 new iccid : 9990012221"

Comment: What in the world!?!  Why does this have 3 upvotes?  It is indubitably wrong. Proof: https://3v4l.org/DfJda  It nukes the digit before the space, the space, and the digit after the space.

Comment: the previous one doesn't work in all case (ie: "3 835" => "35"). SOLUTION :

preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $str)